# meaning of have a sequel to match

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of a sequel to match in used in the following sentence

> The U.S.-China talks started with a bang but ended with a whimper as Chinese officials left the site of the talks in Anchorage without a press conference on Friday and the rancour and sparring evident in Thursday’s opening session did not have a sequel to match.

Comment: Can you expand your question.  What is the dictionary definitons of "sequel" that you are using.  What does "to match" mean for you?  How well do you understand the (harder) words like "rancour and sparring" or the cliche "started with a bang but ended with a whimper"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "[T]he rancour and sparring evident in Thursday’s opening session did not have a sequel to match."

Note a past tense auxiliary verb, 'did', is used.

A simpler clause with similar meaning may be 'there was no subsequent session with similar rancour'.